# Using Windows Workflow Foundation in all applications can be a good idea?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

Is it a good idea use WF for all application sizes? From more simple to more complex applications, considering that all applications follow a workflow, even in most of cases the workflow be implicit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Workflow Foundation is not going to be useful for every single application that you build.  You're going to have to measure the benefits and costs against your project on a case by case basis to determine if it would be viable.  This is really going to be the case for anything you consider using.

While every application, in a sense, has a workflow, Workflow Foundation is a heavy framework, especially for simple workflows that are easily defined, and should only be used when you need to put a significant amount of effort in defining what the workflows of you application are.